# Nullable int validation not showing message for non-numeric values

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm using jQuery validation, and I have the following html:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Weight must be a number." data-val-range="The field Weight must be between 1 and 750." data-val-range-max="999" data-val-range-min="0" id="Weight" name="Weight" type="number" value="" />
<span data-valmsg-for="Weight" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

This is how the property on my model looks like

```
[Range(1, 750)]
public int? Weight { get; set; }
```

When I use a number outside of the range 0..999, the validation fails, and I see the correct message. However, when I use a non-numeric value, such as `abc`, the form passes validation. What am I doing wrong here?

It might be worth noting that using a `double?` works just fine. The same model also has a nullable double property, also decorated with a `Range` attribute. This property renders exactly the same html, except for the `id` and `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `type="number"` to `type="text"` solved my issue.