# .NET MVC client side validation not showing message for property when value invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have read many posts on this subject matter, but I am still battling with my issue. I have a form that has a 14 properties and 5 complex types with custom template editors. Client side validation works for all properties and custom template editors, but the property below. If I enter text, it erases the entire contents of the text box with no message. However if I enter 2., I receive the error message saying it must be an number. Has anyone experienced this behavior? This happens on a few of my other forms as well.

As a side note: Should client side validate the nullable int range? Seems like it does not unless I add a range validator. Thank you.

**UPDATE**
This is actually happening for all my int? properties

**Model**

```
[Display(Name = "Lifetime")]
public int? Life { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditPerson", "Maintenance", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "operation-form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonId)
    @Html.Hidden("ModifiedBy", User.Identity.Name)

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row person-field">
          <div class="col-md-6 field-name">
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Life)
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Life, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "to-center routebox" } })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Life, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
}

 @section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Comment: you are right, you have to use a range validator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your using a modern browser, the problem may be the use of `@Html.EditorFor()` By default this will add `type="number"` to the input and as a result will generate the browsers implementation of a number control. I have only tested this using Chrome, but it appears that if you enter text that not a valid number, the the browser intercepts it and prevents the `value` attribute being set. Now when you post back, `Life` is null and therefore valid and when you return the view, the `ModelState` value is null explaining why it appears to *"erase the entire contents of the text box with no message"*.

You can test this by changing it to `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Life)` which will render `type="text"`. Now when you enter text and try to submit, unobtrusive validation will prevent submission and display *"The field Life must be a number"*. As for validating the range, if you do not add an appropriate attribute to the property (e.g `[Range(0, int.MaxValue)]`) then there is nothing for `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` to test so it posts back, however its validated on the server and when you return the view, a validation error will be displayed such as *"The value '999999999999999999999999999999999999999999' is invalid"*.

Answer (score 1):

Once I figured out that int? was the problem, I found a solution here:

[Nullable int validation not showing message for non-numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807918/nullable-int-validation-not-showing-message-for-non-numeric-values)

All I did was add the data type annotation to all `int?`. Not sure why this works yet.

```
[Display(Name = "Lifetime")]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
public int? Life { get; set; }
```

Comment: While this may indeed give you the results you're looking for, it's not "fixing the problem", it's just masking it.  This will likely come back to bite you in some other way.  Unfortunately, you don't show enough of your actual model and actual pages to diagnose the real problem.

Comment: I understand I am masking it. The rest of the view looks exactly like my snippet for each property, and I would think the rest of model would not influence this error per se because the error occurs on all `int?` properties and is not model specific. That is why I left off the other code that would have just seemed like noise.

Comment: There are many small, subtle things that can affect validation, Without seeing the entire page as a whole, and the model as a whole, it's hard to see the entire picture.  In addition, what javascript are you including, what global filters are installed, etc.. there's lots of places where a problem can hide.

Comment: Also, do you have any int.cshtml or Object.cshtml editor templates?

Comment: understandable and I will post my entire model and view later tonight. On the surface I do not see any special filters or templates as you mentioned, but I will keep a look out.

Answer (score 0):

There are such options:

1. Use `[Range(0, int.MaxValue)]`
2. Use `[RegularExpression("([0-9]+)")]`
3. Use `[Integer]` from [DataAnnotationExtensions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/Integer/Create)
4. Use your own custom `ValidationAttribute` with registering on client-side

Comment: thank you. I have not tried the extensions before, but using the range and the regular expressions do not stop the textbox from getting rid of all the contents. The range does validate an actual integer, but if I enter text it still erases the field with no message